# how to fix the error while im trying to connect private ec2 instance through public ec2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I'm creating 2 amazon elastic cloud compute instances one is public and one is pvt. 
How can I access the private instance through public instance?
What are the commands to execute?
I've tried with

```
ssh -p port number public-host name private-host name
```

I got the error as **access denied**

Comment: You need to create a virtual private cloud (VPC) for the two cloud instances to talk to each other. [Read](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-vpc.html).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your situation is:

- An Amazon EC2 instance in a Public Subnet (connected to an Internet Gateway)
- An Amazon EC2 instance in a Private Subnet (not connected to an Internet Gateway)
- You can successfully SSH into the Public instance
- You then wish to SSH into the Private instance

You will need to use the standard SSH command:

```
ssh -i pemfile.pem ec2-user@PRIVATE-IP-ADDRESS
```

Some things to note:

- Connect to the Private instance via its Private IP address. In fact, it should not have a public DNS name or public IP address
- You will need to provide an key (pem) file to authenticate

There are two ways to provide the pem file:

- Use Agent Forwarding in your SSH connection, or
- Copy the pem file to the Public instance and use it as part of the ssh command (as shown above). This is bad from a security perspective since somebody who gets into the Public instance would then be able to access the Private instance.

Also, it depends on whether you are using the *same* key or a *different* key on the private computer. The easiest is to use the same key, which makes Agent Forwarding easier.

See: [Securely Connect to Linux Instances Running in a Private Amazon VPC | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/)

Comment: If you're on a network with access controls (firewalls, etc) your administrators might have blocked port 22 / SSH protocol.